# Difference between Long and Object data type in VBA

Tags: vba, variables

In VBA, the Long and Object data type are both 4-bytes, which is the size of a memory address. Does this mean that, technically, the Object data type doesn't do anything that a Long couldn't do? If yes, then is it safe to say that the Object data type exists simply to make it easier for the programmer to distinguish between the purpose of the variable?

This question came up as I was considering Win32 API function declarations. They are often times declared as Long, and, unless I am mistaken, their return value is simply a memory address. Seems like defining these functions as Object would have been more appropriate, then.

Am I totally off? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Object` hides a large amount of underlying complexity, its underlying 4 byte pointer *must* point to a COM objects vTable/IDispatch - you can't assign the address of anything else to it and expect it to work.

Comment: I didn't know it could only point to COM objects. So, what does this say about Win32 API functions? If they return COM pointers then why aren't they declared as Object rather than Long?

Comment: Most of Win32 that uses COM is implemented using COM interfaces directly rather than as exported functions, I suppose in theory that if you found one that did return such (e.g the last argument of COM's CoCreateInstance) you could pass the argument `as Object`

Answer (score 1):

Based on VBA/MSDN help:

> **Long (long integer) variables** are stored as signed 32-bit (4-byte)
>   numbers ranging in value from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.

and the other definition:

> **Object variables** are stored as 32-bit (4-byte) addresses that refer to
>   objects. Using the Set statement, a variable declared as an Object can
>   have any object reference assigned to it.

From practical point of view they are both different and used in different situation. Which are essential: **Long >> refers to numbers** and **Object >> refers to object**.

Look into the following VBA code (for Excel) where I added comments which is allowed and which is not:

```
Sub test_variables()

    Dim A As Object
    Dim B As Long

    'both below are not allowed, throwing exceptions
    'A = 1000
    'Set B = ActiveSheet

    'both are appropriate
    Set A = ActiveSheet
    B = 1000
End Sub
```

Finally, in terms of API it's better to stay with original declaration and not manipulate with that to avoid any risk on unexpected behaviour of API functions.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I am aware of how these data types are used and that they cannot be interchanged. I am just confused why Win32 API functions return a pointer that is defined as a Long rather than an Object. Longs can only hold half of all possible address values, for one thing. Second, for the sake of consistency I would think that Object ought to be used exclusively for pointers, and Long exclusively for signed integers.